# IllegalFormatConversionException: d != kotlin.Unit

Tags: android, kotlin

necesito ayuda con una excepcion. He escrito un codigo en Java y despues me pidieron que lo pase a Kotlin. He usado la funcion de Android Studio para hacer eso junto con un par de retoques mios que tuve que hacer en otras clases.

```
package celer.db

import celer.entity.Cliente
import groovyjarjarantlr4.v4.runtime.misc.NotNull
import java.sql.SQLException

class PagosDAO : DBConnection() {
    fun movimientos(@NotNull cliente: Cliente?) = try {
        val sql =
            "SELECT * FROM public.pagos WHERE idclientes = %d ORDER BY fecha_ing DESC LIMIT 10"
        if (cliente != null) {
            executeQuery(String.format(sql, cliente.getIdClientes()))
        }
        while (result!!.next()) {
            val columnas = result!!.metaData.columnCount
            for (i in 1..columnas) {
                print(result!!.getString(i) + "\t|\t")
            }
            println()
        }
    } catch (e: SQLException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

La linea `executeQuery(String.format(sql, cliente.getIdClientes()))` es la que salta la excepcion. La solucion que he encontre que fue la de cambiar meter `String.format()`pero el codigo lo tiene y parece no funcionar

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En error es que el placeholder `%d` de consulta SQL espera recibir un número entero pero lo que le estás pasando es de tipo `kotlin.Unit`, que es el equivalente al `void` de Java. Esto significa que el método `getIdClientes()` de tu clase `Cliente` no retorna ningún valor.

La solución es hacer que el *return type* de ese método sea un entero, como `Int` o `Long`. Ejemplo:

```
fun getIdClientes(): Int {
    return numeroEntero
}
```

Comment: Con que eso era el error, me habia hecho la cabeza con el tema del padding y otras cosas mas. Como me habia enroscado con eso, no me di cuenta del return